# Varbinary/Blob in filter or function not supported

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery

I'm trying to select the first non-null value between multiple columns 
in one table while selecting columns from another table as well.
The SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date, coalesce(t2.source, t2.src, t2.data_source) as source,
       coalesce(t2.medium, t2.mdm, t2.data_medium) as medium
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.date >= '2020/01/01';
```

I'm getting an error message "SQL Error[1815][HY000]: (conn=3186) Internal error: VARBINARY/BLOB in filter or function is not supported."
How do I solve this problem? I'm doing this in Mariadb by the way.

Comment: What column or columns are BLOBs?  What are the data types of the other columns?

Comment: Date column is of datetime data type. All other columns are stored as text. I only face this problem when joining tables. If I just select coalesce(t2.source, t2.src, t2.data_source) as source from table2 t2, it works fine.